# React using state vs using local variable, state works but local variable does not

Tags: reactjs

I tried to create a function to retrieve all the users in a database, however, if I tried to just use the local variable like in the image, it does not work at all. If I tried to useState (the commented code), it works when I think there should be no difference between them. The users list is being used for the map function in the TableBody part.

```
const RegisteredUsers = () => {
    //const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
    let customers = [];

    useEffect(async () => {
        await userService.getAll().then(customersList =>{
            //setCustomers(customersList);
            customers = customersList;
        }).catch((err)=> {
            console.log("Error: ", err);
        });
    });

    return (
        <Box
            sx={{
                backgroundColor: "background.default",
                p: 3,
            }}
        >
            <Card>
                <Divider/>
                <Box
                    sx={{
                        alignItems: "center",
                        display: "flex",
                        flexWrap: "wrap",
                        m: -1,
                        p: 2,
                    }}
                >
                    <Box
                        sx={{
                            m: 1,
                            maxWidth: "100%",
                            width: 500,
                        }}
                    >
                        <TextField
                            fullWidth
                            InputProps={{
                                startAdornment: (
                                    <InputAdornment position="start">
                                        <SearchIcon fontSize="small"/>
                                    </InputAdornment>
                                ),
                            }}
                            placeholder="Search customers"
                            variant="outlined"
                        />
                    </Box>
                    <Box
                        sx={{
                            m: 1,
                            width: 240,
                        }}
                    >
                        <TextField
                            label="Sort By"
                            name="sort"
                            select
                            SelectProps={{native: true}}
                            variant="outlined"
                        >
                            {sortOptions.map((option) => (
                                <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                                    {option.label}
                                </option>
                            ))}
                        </TextField>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
                <Scrollbar>
                    <Box sx={{minWidth: 700}}>
                        <Table>
                            <TableHead>
                                <TableRow>
                                    <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                                        <Checkbox color="primary"/>
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Email</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Role</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Company Id</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="right">Actions</TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableHead>
                            <TableBody>
                                {customers.map((customer) => (
                                    <TableRow hover key={customer.id}>
                                        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                                            <Checkbox color="primary"/>
                                        </TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>
                                            <Box
                                                sx={{
                                                    alignItems: "center",
                                                    display: "flex",
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <Avatar
                                                    alt={customer.client_name}
                                                    sx={{
                                                        height: 42,
                                                        width: 42,
                                                    }}
                                                />
                                                <Box sx={{ml: 1}}>
                                                    <Link color="inherit" variant="subtitle2">
                                                        {customer.client_name}
                                                    </Link>
                                                </Box>
                                            </Box>
                                        </TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>
                                            <Typography color="textSecondary" variant="body2">
                                                {customer.email}
                                            </Typography>
                                        </TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>{customer.role}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>{customer.company_id}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">
                                            <IconButton>
                                                <PencilAltIcon fontSize="small"/>
                                            </IconButton>
                                            <IconButton>
                                                <ArrowRightIcon fontSize="small"/>
                                            </IconButton>
                                        </TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>
                                ))}
                            </TableBody>
                        </Table>
                    </Box>
                </Scrollbar>
                <TablePagination
                    component="div"
                    count={customers.length}
                    onPageChange={() => {
                    }}
                    onRowsPerPageChange={() => {
                    }}
                    page={0}
                    rowsPerPage={5}
                    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
                />

                <Comments/>
            </Card>
        </Box>
    )
};
```

This is my userService.getAll()

```
export const userService = {
    getAll,
    getById
};

async function getAll() {
    let customers = [];
    await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users", {
        headers: authHeader()
    }).then(customersList => {
        customers.push(...customersList.data.users);
    }).catch((err)=> {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
    })

    return customers;
}
```

I tried many methods including using async function since I thought that it could be the case that React renders before value assigned to customers, but it does not work as well.

I am new to React so any helps would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is precisely why you need a *state*.

In your first attempt, the component has rendered before you assign a new value to `customers` and won't re-render.

> I thought that it could be the case that React renders before value assigned to customers

Precisely as you guessed, you have two ways to instruct a component to re-render:

- change the component state (as in the hook)
- change the component props

One of these two option is required to instruct react to recompute the component

Answer (score 0):

The key hint is that, useState will preserve its value through rerenders and changing state will trigger rerender. It means that if you store something in normal variable after render, it will not show up in your DOM because there is still value from previous render. And if you trigger new render, your variable is redeclared with empty array and you are where you have been before fetch.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime local variable value will be called synchronously (no idea when it will be populated with data ), add following check to your map to make sure it runs when the value is there:

sortOptions && sortOptions?.map (...)

Also, as you are getting the values from API, react recomment using state with useState.